# For odd prime $p$, $\Bbb F^\times_{p^2}\subset\mathrm{GL}_2(\Bbb F_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> $\newcommand{\sl}{\mathrm{SL}}\newcommand{\gl}{\mathrm{GL}}$Let $G = \sl_2(\Bbb F_p)$ with $p$ and odd prime. Prove that the Sylow $l$-subgroup of $G$ are cyclic for every odd prime $l$ dividing $|G|$. Hint: $\Bbb F^\times_{p^2}\subset\gl_2(\Bbb F_p)$.

My question is basically why the hint is true. Note that $|\sl_2(\Bbb F_p)| = p(p^2-1)$ and if $l = p$ then strictly upper triangular matrices form a cyclic sylow $p$ subgroup. If $l\neq p$ then $l\mid p^2-1 = |\Bbb F_{p^2}^\times|$. Since $\Bbb F^\times_{p^2}$ is a cyclic group, if the hint is true then I can use it somehow.

$$\Bbb F_{p^2}^\times = \langle 1,\alpha\rangle_{\Bbb F_p}\to\gl_2(\Bbb F_p),\quad a+b\alpha\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} a & rb\\ b & a\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\alpha^2 = r$ for some $r\in\Bbb F_p$. So, only the elements of the form $a+b\alpha$ with $a^2-b^2r=1$ get mapped to $\sl_2(\Bbb F_p)$.

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ is also a 2-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{F}_p$. So multiplication by a fixed non-zero element of $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ can be thought of as an invertible linear transformation from the said 2-dimensional space to itself.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh I see I only thought $\Bbb F_p^2$ as $2$-dim v.s. / $\Bbb F_p$... I was hoping some explicit form to make $\Bbb F_{p^2}^\times\subset\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb F_p)$... Now I guess it's not true

Comment: Yeah. That way we can only embed $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}^*$ into $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_p)$. Only the norm $1$ elements, i.e. those in the cyclic subgroup of order $p+1$, go into $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_p)$. But the cyclic group of order $p-1$ poses no problems.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm not sure what norm you're talking so I edit the post which I think is equivalent to what you're saying. But how do you know they form a cyclic subgroup of order $p+1$?

Comment: It is the field norm. When we have a Galois extension $K/F$ it takes the simple form
$$N:=N^K_F: x\mapsto \prod_{\sigma\in Gal(K/F)}\sigma(x).$$ So with $K=\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$, $F=\Bbb{F}_p$ we have $N(x)=x^{p+1}$.

Comment: Using your concrete description of the extension field, the non-trivial automorphism maps $\alpha\to\alpha^p=-\alpha$ (because the non-trivial automorphism IS the Frobenius).

Comment: So $$\pmatrix{a&rb\cr b&a\cr}^{p+1}=(a^2-rb^2)I_2.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm not very used to field norm but anyway I understood your last comment. But how do you know the existence of non-unit element such that $a^2-rb^2 = 1$? And what if $l\mid p-1$?

Comment: $C_{p-1}$ you can embed into $SL_2$ as the subgroup of diagonal matrices.

Comment: $N:\Bbb{F}_{p^2}^*\to\Bbb{F}_p^*$ maps $N(x)=x^{p+1}$. A surjective homomorphism between cyclic groups.